# Exception not running PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, exception

I got the code:

```
DECLARE

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO articulo VALUES (33, 'Mesa 33', 1000.45463, 50.2345, 200.23459, 20, 'Conjunto');
    INSERT INTO articulo VALUES (34, 'Mesa 34', 300.4500, 15.2379 , 1.2379 , 5, 'kid 4');

    SELECT * FROM articulo;

    INSERT INTO cliente (id_clie, nom_clie, rfc_clie, tel_clie, dir_clie, suspendido) VALUES (44,'Rosa Almaran', 'R7XA-910101', '5544466677', 'sur 24', 0);

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION ''All fields are required'';  
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION ''This is an exception'';   
END;
```

Which I read from [here](http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/articulos/48/Excepciones-en-PLSQL.aspx).
When I try to run the code I get:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 5: INSERT INTO Product VALUES (33, 'Mesa 33', 1000.45463, 50 ....
        ^
```

I want PostgreSQL to show an exception depending of the type of exception it encounters.

Any help would be thanked!

Comment: The syntax error tells you that your query is broken, fix that and you should get the exception :)

Comment: What do you mean with the query is broken @Wolph?

Comment: The syntaxerror means that Postgres doesn't understand your query syntax somehow. My guess is that you are missing your function definition.

Comment: The problem is that I am not creating any function. I just want to see the Exceptions thrown.

Comment: This type of exception handling is specific to the PL/pgSQL context, since Postgres 9.0 you're not required to use a function anymore and can do it with a `DO $$ <YOUR_CODE> $$ language 'plpgsql';` statement.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM articulo;` :: no target for query-result, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your code in a [DO statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html):

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO articulo VALUES (33, 'Mesa 33', 1000.45463, 50.2345, 200.23459, 20, 'Conjunto');
    INSERT INTO articulo VALUES (34, 'Mesa 34', 300.4500, 15.2379 , 1.2379 , 5, 'kid 4');

    SELECT * FROM articulo;

    INSERT INTO cliente (id_clie, nom_clie, rfc_clie, tel_clie, dir_clie, suspendido) VALUES (44,'Rosa Almaran', 'R7XA-910101', '5544466677', 'sur 24', 0);

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'All fields are required';  
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'This is an exception';   
END;
$$;
```

Comment: I used the code you provided but I keep having the same problem: ERROR: syntax error at or near "All"
LINE 15: RAISE EXCEPTION '' All fields are required ';
                                              ^

Comment: Just noticed that there's a syntax error there as well, it should just use `'` instead of `''`. I'll change it :)

Comment: Awesome. Finally got it running! Thanks a lot @Wolph